# How can I fix my Python TCP/IP server to receive messages?

Tags: python, tcp, ip

I am very new to creating such programs. I am trying to create a TCP server that can receive messages from any device that connects to it so I created the following program but it does not work, why is this the case?

```
import socket

def receive_messages():
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Define the server address and port
    server_address = ("127.0.0.1", 1234)

    # Bind the socket to the server address and port
    server_socket.bind(server_address)

    # Listen for incoming connections
    server_socket.listen(1)

    print('Waiting for a connection...')

    # Accept a client connection
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print('Connected to:', client_address)

    try:
        while True:
            # Receive data from the client
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            if data:
                # Process the received data
                message = data.decode()
                print('Received message:', message)

                # Send an acknowledgement back to the client
                client_socket.sendall(b'ACK')
            else:
                # No more data from the client
                print('Connection closed by the client.')
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        client_socket.close()
        server_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    receive_messages()
```

I tried different ports and cant seem to get it to work. I tried to connect to it through a phone app and that does not work either.

Comment: You're opening port on `localhost` which means that it can be accessed only from your machine. If you want it to be accessible from everywhere, change `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I see, I changed it and it still does not work, could it be anything else?

Comment: Yes, it could be some sort of firewall installed which doesn't allow connection.

Comment: It works fine, maybe you are testing wrongly. Try opening another window on the machine and type `curl http://localhost:1234/` and see if you get any output from your python server.